# Signature pad not able to draw in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, signature

need some help here, my signature pad for some reason can't draw anything after I put it in a new project.

I have already did this:
npm install --save signature_pad

I also included this inside my code: (sorry I don't know how to combine 2 js in jsfiddle)
https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/blob/master/example/js/signature_pad.js

How I add it inside my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/signature'.$object3->id) }}">

          {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
          {{ csrf_field() }}

 <p align="center">
                    <canvas id="signature-canvas" style="width:650px;height:420px;max-width:100%;border:8px #CCC solid;background-color: white;"></canvas>
                    </p>

                    <div id="signature-message"></div>

                    <div id="signature-buttons">
                      <input type="button" id="clear-signature-btn" value="Clear">
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="signature" id="signature-data" value="">

                    <br>
                    <div class="signature_pad_save">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-signature-btn">Save</button>
                    </div>

</form>
<script src="{{ asset('js/signature_pad.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/signaturetest.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ygfspL0c/ Here is the code to my signature, sorry they keep giving me an error when i try to put the link inside

Comment: How are you including that file? [I added the CDN for it and it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/661gjnjh/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have updated the question, sorry for the late reply

Comment: It inside public/js folder

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i realize the problem was actually coming from the extend and section part. If i remove them I am able to draw out the signature but why? Is there any way for me to draw the signature with my header all those?